Linux DMA on ZYNQ
I have a linux driver that manages a Xilinx MCDMA IP. The MCDMA is configured to have 8 S2MM channels, basically allowing some custom data aquisition IP to write to the DMA. I also have written a driver that is heavily inspired by this one: Linux MCDMA.
To quickly explain the functionality, the user sends IOCTLS to the driver that will in turn start the transfer (from DMA to DDR) on one of the channels, with one of the buffer descriptors and the user can also send an IOCTL to wait for the end of the transfer. The area which is allocated for the transfered data between the user and kernel space is shared.
In its globality the driver works however there is a peculiar bug.
The custom data generator IP sends data to the different MCDMA channels by bursts of 64 words. When the user alls an IOCTL to start the transfer it references the size of the transfer through a struct that is shared between the kernel and the user:
#define BUFFER_COUNT 4                  // Buffer descriptors per channel
#define BUFFER_SIZE (256 * BUFFER_COUNT * sizeof(unsigned int))     /* must match driver exactly */


struct channel_buffer {
    unsigned int buffer[BUFFER_SIZE / sizeof(unsigned int)];
    enum proxy_status { PROXY_NO_ERROR = 0, PROXY_BUSY = 1, PROXY_TIMEOUT = 2, PROXY_ERROR = 3 } status;
    unsigned int length;
} __attribute__ ((aligned (64)));       // 64 byte alignment required for DMA

You can also see the shared buffer as well as the status variable.
When the user asks for lets say 256 samples (length = 256) the buffer is actually only filled with 64 data samples and the remaining 192 integers are zeros. Actually no matter the length demanded by the user (as long as it is above or equal to the burst size 256) returns 64 real data samples followed by zeros.
It would be a problem if on the next request the user would receive the 64 words that are not contiguous to the ones before, but they are! So that prompts for an easy but dirty fix where instead of doing 1 request, you just do 4!
However I am not satisfied with such and answer, and I do not seem to understand where the problem is comming from. Changing the size of the burst from the data generator IP to the DMA does not work either, as the MCDMA decides to simply stop responding (tready=0) if the size is above 64.
Therefor I strongly think that the problem seems to be in the driver.
Here is the defenition for a dma_channel struct:
struct proxy_bd {
    struct completion cmp;
    dma_cookie_t cookie;
    dma_addr_t dma_handle;
    struct scatterlist sglist;
};

struct dma_proxy_channel {
    struct channel_buffer *buffer_table_p;  /* user to kernel space interface */
    dma_addr_t buffer_phys_addr;
    struct device *proxy_device_p;              /* character device support */
    struct device *dma_device_p;
    dev_t dev_node;
    struct cdev cdev;
    struct class *class_p;

    struct proxy_bd bdtable[BUFFER_COUNT];

    struct dma_chan *channel_p;             /* dma support */
    u32 direction;                      /* DMA_MEM_TO_DEV or DMA_DEV_TO_MEM */
    int bdindex;
};

Here are the functions that are starting and finishing a dma request:
static void start_transfer(struct dma_proxy_channel *pchannel_p)
{
    enum dma_ctrl_flags flags = DMA_CTRL_ACK | DMA_PREP_INTERRUPT;
    struct dma_async_tx_descriptor *chan_desc;
    struct dma_device *dma_device = pchannel_p->channel_p->device;
    int bdindex = pchannel_p->bdindex;

    //printk("Starting transfer on channel: %px, BD: %d\n", (void *)pchannel_p->buffer_phys_addr, bdindex);
    /* A single entry scatter gather list is used as it's not clear how to do it with a simpler method.
     * Get a descriptor for the transfer ready to submit
     */
    sg_init_table(&pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].sglist, 1);
    sg_dma_address(&pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].sglist) = pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].dma_handle;
    sg_dma_len(&pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].sglist) = pchannel_p->buffer_table_p[bdindex].length;

    chan_desc = dma_device->device_prep_slave_sg(pchannel_p->channel_p, &pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].sglist, 1, 
                        pchannel_p->direction, flags, NULL);

    if (!chan_desc) {
        printk(KERN_ERR "dmaengine_prep*() error\n");
    } else {
        chan_desc->callback = sync_callback;
        chan_desc->callback_param = &pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].cmp;

        /* Initialize the completion for the transfer and before using it
         * then submit the transaction to the DMA engine so that it's queued
         * up to be processed later and get a cookie to track it's status
         */
        init_completion(&pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].cmp);

        pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].cookie = dmaengine_submit(chan_desc);
        if (dma_submit_error(pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].cookie)) {
            printk("Submit error\n");
            return;
        }

        /* Start the DMA transaction which was previously queued up in the DMA engine
         */
        dma_async_issue_pending(pchannel_p->channel_p);
    }
}

/* Wait for a DMA transfer that was previously submitted to the DMA engine
 */
static void wait_for_transfer(struct dma_proxy_channel *pchannel_p)
{
    unsigned long timeout = msecs_to_jiffies(3000);
    enum dma_status status;
    int bdindex = pchannel_p->bdindex;

    pchannel_p->buffer_table_p[bdindex].status = PROXY_BUSY;

    /* Wait for the transaction to complete, or timeout, or get an error
     */
    timeout = wait_for_completion_timeout(&pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].cmp, timeout);
    status = dma_async_is_tx_complete(pchannel_p->channel_p, pchannel_p->bdtable[bdindex].cookie, NULL, NULL);
    if (timeout == 0)  {
        pchannel_p->buffer_table_p[bdindex].status  = PROXY_TIMEOUT;
        printk(KERN_ERR "DMA timed out on channel %d\n", bdindex);
    } else if (status != DMA_COMPLETE) {
        pchannel_p->buffer_table_p[bdindex].status = PROXY_ERROR;
        printk(KERN_ERR "DMA returned completion callback status of: %s\n",
               status == DMA_ERROR ? "error" : "in progress");
    } else
    {
        pchannel_p->buffer_table_p[bdindex].status = PROXY_NO_ERROR;
    }
    
}


As you can see they are pretty straight forward, and resemble 100% to the original drivers functions.
I have started tracing the actual AXI transaction and they seem to confirm that the 192 zeros are being sent to the DDR
Any ideas on how to correct the bug?
